VBA to paste in to PPT as embedded table from Excel
I am using the code below and it works fine to paste as a picture. It took me a lot (like 15hours) of hunting and pecking on the internet to put this code together (I know very little VBA...I record macros). I was just asked to have it paste as an embedded table. I am not sure how to do this in VBA. I am grateful for any help anyone can provide?
This is pulling each row off a 250+ lines of a worksheet, along with the header row.
You'll notice I 'deactivated' quite a few lines of code using " ' " but I left them in the module (because I am that inept in VBA but desperate)
I am truly grateful for any help.
Sub CopyRangeToPresentation() 
'Slides for 
'Variables 
    Dim PP As PowerPoint.Application 
    Dim PPpres As PowerPoint.Presentation 
    Dim PPslide As PowerPoint.Slide 
    Dim SlideTitle As String 
    Dim lRow As Long 
    Dim i As Integer 
'Fider 
    lRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _ 
    After:=Range("A1"), _ 
    LookAt:=xlPart, _ 
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _ 
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _ 
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious, _ 
    MatchCase:=False).row 
'New presentation 
    Set PP = New PowerPoint.Application 
    Set PPpres = PP.Presentations.Add 
    Set PP = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application") 
    PP.Visible = 1 
    For i = 1 To lRow 
'New slide 
    Set PPslide = PPpres.Slides.Add(i, ppLayoutBlank) 
    PP.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide 
    PPpres.PageSetup.SlideSize = ppSlideSizeOnScreen 
    PP.ActiveWindow.WindowState = ppWindowMaximized 
    PPslide.Select 
'Copy 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K1").CopyPicture _ 
'Range("A1").Copy 
'PPslide.Shapes.Paste 
'PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True 
'PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True 
    With PPslide.Shapes.Paste(1) 
    .Left = 0 
    .Top = 2.55 * 72 ' 72 points=1in 
    .Height = 72 * 3.39 
    .Width = 72 * 9.8 
    PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True 
    End With 
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 11)).CopyPicture _ 
    Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture 
'Paste 
' PPslide.Shapes.Paste.Select 
' PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True 
' PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True 
    With PPslide.Shapes.Paste(1) 
    .Left = 0 
    .Top = 2.92 * 72 ' 72 points=1in 
    .Height = 72 * 3.39 
    .Width = 72 * 9.8 
    PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True 
    End With 
'Title 
    Next i 
'Memory 
    PP.Activate 
    Set PPslide = Nothing 
    Set PPpres = Nothing 
    Set PP = Nothing 
End Sub

I used the code pasted and it worked well to paste in to PPT as a picture, but now I need it to paste as an embedded table but have no idea how to accomplish this.

Edit - code with add new scripts from comment below

Sub CopyRangeToPresentation()
'Slides for project test module
'Variables
  Dim PP As PowerPoint.Application
  Dim PPpres As PowerPoint.Presentation
  Dim PPslide As PowerPoint.Slide
  Dim SlideTitle As String
  Dim lRow As Long
  Dim i As Integer
      
'Fider
  lRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    searchdirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).row
'New presentation
    Set PP = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set PPpres = PP.Presentations.Add
    Set PP = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    PP.Visible = 1

    For i = 1 To lRow
'New slide
      Set PPslide = PPpres.Slides.Add(i, ppLayoutBlank)
      PP.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide
      PPpres.PageSetup.SlideSize = ppSlideSizeOnScreen
      PP.ActiveWindow.WindowState = ppWindowMaximized
      PPslide.Select
'Copy
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K1").Copy  ' copy Excel range with format
      'Range("A1").Copy
      'PPslide.Shapes.Paste
      'PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
      'PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
      
   '   With PPslide.Shapes.Paste(1)
  '.Left = 0
  '.Top = 2.55 * 72 ' 72 points=1in
  '.Height = 72 * 3.39
  '        .Width = 72 * 9.8
  '        PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters,   
    True
  'End With
    
  ' Application.CutCopyMode = False
      
      
  Set PPslide = PP.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(1, 12)  ' ppLayoutBlank=12
  PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial 10 'ppPasteOLEObject=10 ' paste as OLEObject
  With PPslide.Shapes(PPslide.Shapes.Count)
  
        .Height = 72 * 6.39
        .Width = 72 * 9.8
        .Left = PP.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth / 2 - .Width / 2
        .Top = PP.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight / 2 - .Height / 1
      End With
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    
    '   Set PP = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 11)).Copy ' copy Excel range with format
    
   ' Set PPslide = PP.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(1, 12)  '     
     ppLayoutBlank=12
     PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial 10 'ppPasteOLEObject=10 ' paste as 
     OLEObject
     With PPslide.Shapes(PPslide.Shapes.Count)

        .Height = 72 * 6.39
        .Width = 72 * 9.8
        .Left = PP.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth / 2 - .Width 
    / 2
        .Top = PP.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight / 2 - .Height 
    / 10
    End With
   ' Application.CutCopyMode = False
         
  'Paste
     ' PPslide.Shapes.Paste.Select
     ' PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
     ' PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
     
  '           With PPslide.Shapes.Paste(1)
  '.Left = 0
  '.Top = 2.92 * 72 ' 72 points=1in
  '.Height = 72 * 3.39
  '        .Width = 72 * 9.8
  '        PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, 
    True
  'End With
 
    
'Title
Next i

    'Memory
      PP.Activate
      Set PPslide = Nothing
      Set PPpres = Nothing
      Set PP = Nothing

End Sub


Using ppPasteOLEObject as the 2nd argument to paste as OLEObject (embedded Excel table).
    Set PP = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    ' Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K1").Copy ' copy Excel range with format
    Set PPslide = PP.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(1, 12)  ' ppLayoutBlank=12
    PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial 10 'ppPasteOLEObject=10 ' paste as OLEObject
    With PPslide.Shapes(PPslide.Shapes.Count)
        .Height = 72 * 3.39
        .Width = 72 * 9.8
        .Left = PP.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth / 2 - .Width / 2
        .Top = PP.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight / 2 - .Height / 2
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False


That is very close to exactly perfect! :) The problem I am having now is the macro seems to read from bottom to top. It is starting with the last row in my spreadsheet, which is in alphabetical order, so slide 1 is Zebra and slide 260 is Apple. (for example). Did I add your code in, incorrectly? (I have too many characters for a 'comment' so I'll post the entire edited code (with your new scripts) above.

Slides.Add(1, 12)  insert the slide before the first slide, that is the new inserted slide is the first one after it. Try looping in reverse order For i = lRow To 1 Step -1
